# unknown error when building react native project

Tags: react-native

Error:

```
Unable to resolve module /Volumes/My Space/projects/react_native_expo/app_two/assets/bg32.jpg from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: 
None of these files exist:
  * bg32.jpg
  * ../../../../Volumes/My Space/projects/react_native_expo/app_two/assets/bg32.jpg/index(.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.android.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.android.css|.native.css|.css)
  53 |   return (
  54 |     <View style={styles.container}>
> 55 |       <ImageBackground source={require('/Volumes/My Space/projects/react_native_expo/app_two/assets/bg32.jpg')} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
     |                                         ^
  56 |       <NavigationContainer>
  57 |           <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MApp" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
  58 |             <Stack.Screen name="Mapp" component={MappScreen}/>
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:127:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:271:43)
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:176:21
    at resolveDependencies (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:56:25)
    at visit (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:107:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

would someone give me any solution for this? the image I am using exists in the assets folder but it keeps showing the same error from the first time,
but it works properly on expo go during the coding process.